# Pulsating CSS circle always on top

Tags: css, z-index

ive been at this for a while now, and i cant seem to figure out how to fix it. I have one circle that the user is supposed to be able to press, and i want another circle behind it, that pulsates. When the BG circle isnt set to pulsate, its displayed behind the main circle, but when i set it to pulsate, it moves to the top.

```css
    .mainClick{
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: rgba(75,75,75, 1);
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transition: 0.5s;
      z-index: 2;
      margin-top: -185px;
    }
    
    
    
    .mainClick:hover{
      background-color: rgba(75,75,75, 0.1);
    }
    
    
    
    .dot {
      border: 50px solid rgba(100, 200, 100, 1);
      background: transparent;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      /*  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
      -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
      animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
      margin: 0 auto;
      transition: 0.5s;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes pulse {
     0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;
     }
     25% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.1;
     }
     50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0.3;
     }
     75% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
     }
     100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.0;
     }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
     0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;
     }
    
     25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
     }
     100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.0;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="mainClick"></div>
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/a8cwo5ne/

Comment: https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/09/css-stacking-contexts-wtf/index.html

Comment: Oh, thanks! Works now, but now i need to find a way to get both of the circles to be in the same place again :'( Know any good ways? Everyone says margin:0auto, but it doesnt really work with position: absolute..

Comment: Can you provide an updated fiddle including what you have changed now?

Comment: i updated the one thats linked in the post now :)

Comment: That seems to be still the original one, please add the revision number.

Comment: kinda new to jsfiddle, sorry. Heres the new one https://jsfiddle.net/a8cwo5ne/8/

Comment: You could try and position them both absolute, and use `calc` to make up for the different offset this will need due to the different circle sizes, https://jsfiddle.net/a8cwo5ne/9/ Another option might be to put `.dot` into `mainClick` maybe, so that the dot can be positioned using mainClick as reference point.

Comment: I know you arent my personal codefixer or anything, but im 99% sure all the code is the same as what you put in the jsfiddle, but as you can see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEVQKb It doesnt seem to work on the full project.. Any idea what ive done wrong? (used codepen, because jsfiddle just gave a bunch of wierd errors)